# probabilities are taken from a sample of $200$ population. Is there a connection\relation between being a vegan and choosing a Political Party?

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance, means, correlation

The chance of a person being vegan is $0.22$, the chance of a person voting for parties A,B,C is

$0.2,0.6,0.2$ respectively.

the probability of a person choosing Party C and being a vegan is $0.1$

the probability of a person choosing Party A and not being a vegan is $0.11$

probabilities are taken from a sample of $200$ population.

Is there a connection\relation between being a vegan and choosing a Political Party ?

$\fbox{Final Answer : 0.359}$

Any ideas what the question want me to calculate ?

the background is about more than one Random variable ($f(x,y)$ probability) \ Variance \ Covariance .

Comment: why have a number as an answer to a yes/no question? I say bad question...

Comment: thats what i keep asking myself but i have $2$ question like that in the homework

Comment: The vegans/total appear to be 18/40 for supporters of A, 6/120 for B, 20/40 for C. That is strong evidence against pure chance. If you calculate the prob of 6/120 if every person has 0.22 chance of being vegan irrespective of party, it is v small.

Comment: so i cant answer the question ? is the question wrong \ missing information ?

Comment: "probabilities are taken from a sample of 200 population" seems irrelevant. If we have probabilities, why talk about samples?